# bind AuthenticationConfig throws exception

Tags: c#, azure-security

I have this piece of code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

var config = builder.Build();
var authenticationConfig = new AuthenticationConfig();
config.Bind(authenticationConfig);
```

I am getting:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IConfigurationRoot' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no accessible extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationRoot' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    SandboxSecurityToken    C:\xxx\Program.cs   35  Active
```

I already imported Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (see: using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration). Any idea what may be missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the NuGet package [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/) to get it to work.